# Does calling Haskell from a main app in C/C++ stop all threads during GC?

Tags: haskell, ffi

I noticed that it is possible to call a Haskell library from C++ using FFI and by initializing the Haskell runtime in the c++ main function. Does this subject all the application's threads to stop the world pauses during garbage collection, or just some of them? Thx.

Comment: Are you talking about Haskell threads or C++ (OS) threads? I'd guess OS threads running Haskell would stop, while those running C++ would continue (until they access Haskell land? not sure). Also keep in mind that a single OS thread can execute many Haskell threads, in general.

Comment: I'm wondering if the garbage collector grabs the process and stops all the threads, even c++ threads not running Haskell code. Or if it stops only threads currently running haskell code, or maybe the thread used to initialize the haskell runtime? I'm thinking of integrating a haskell library into a c++ game engine and I want to make sure that at least the main thread isn't blocked.

Comment: I'm guessing the haskell run time wouldn't bother the main c++ thread, but I just don't know. :I

Comment: If a thread is running c++ code, is there even a OS facility to "stop" or "pause" that thread from the outside? I highly doubt that.